# Mouseover function on dynamically created list items

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a simple user input form that has users input their ID, first name, and last name into 3 separate input boxes. My main objective is to get the data input by user, add it to the "person" object, and display to an unordered list. I've figured that much out.

What I'm trying to do now, is somehow style the content of the list item that was dynamically created, using a mouseover function. I have been trying simple color changes, but I'm super rusty with javascript, and must do this without any jQuery. Any help is appreciated. Just need a push in the right direction, can't get mouseover to work at all for some reason.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<form>
ID Number:<br>
<input type="text" id="idNumber">
<br>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="fName">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="lName">
</form>
<br>
<button type ="submit" onclick="myFunction(list)">Submit</button>
<div id = "container">
<ul id="list"></ul>
</div>


<script>
function myFunction(list){
var text = "";
var person = {idNo:"", firstName:"", lastName:""};
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    idNo = inputs[0].value;
    firstName = inputs[1].value;
    lastName = inputs[2].value;

    text = " "+idNo+" "+firstName+" "+lastName;
}
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver, false);
li.addEventListener("click", mouseClick, false);
var node = document.createTextNode(text);
li.appendChild(node);
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}

function mouseOver(){
li.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li` is not defined in the function `mouseover` use `this` instead -> `this.style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Variables are defined at function scope therefore `var li` is available in `myFunction` but not in `mouseover` function.

Try this sinppet:

```js
function myFunction(list) {
  var text = "";
  var person = {
    idNo: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
  };
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    idNo = inputs[0].value;
    firstName = inputs[1].value;
    lastName = inputs[2].value;

    text = " " + idNo + " " + firstName + " " + lastName;
  }
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver, false);
  //li.addEventListener("click", mouseClick, false);
  var node = document.createTextNode(text);
  li.appendChild(node);
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}

function mouseOver() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<form>
  ID Number:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="idNumber">
  <br>First name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="fName">
  <br>Last name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lName">
</form>
<br>
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction(list)">Submit</button>
<div id="container">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use JS when you can use CSS?

JavaScript:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");

li.classList.add('my-li-class')
```

CSS:

```
.my-li-class:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Anyway if you want to know why your JS doesn't work it's because the li variable is defined outside the mouseOver function scope, do this instead:

```
function mouseOver() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
}
```

Or event this (may not work if li has children):

```
function mouseOver(evt) {
    evt.target.backgroundColor = 'red'
}
```